# Figuring out why my image is not working in the template

Tags: assets, elementcriteriamodel

Possibly a very easy question. Let me explain my flow:

1. I created an asset folder (images)
2. I added the folder in the assets
3. I created in image transforms 'square' which is an image of 500 by 500px.
4. I added a custom field to my homepage called 'hoofdafbeelding' and added an image to it.

I call the image like so:

`{{ entry.hoofdafbeelding.getUrl('square') }}`

I get the following error:

`Object of class Craft\ElementCriteriaModel could not be converted to string`

What am I missing?! How can it be so hard to show an image?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can have more than one Asset in any Assets field, so it always returns to you an *array* of assets. So you just need:

```
{{ entry.hoofdafbeelding.first().getUrl('square') }}
```

...assuming you want the first asset.

Comment: Got it, this works indeed. Should something as rudimentary as this not be explicitly explained in the docs?